# Print the query which is built using db_select()

Tags: 7, database

I want to print the query which is built using [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) in a programmatical way. Is there any API function provided by Drupal Abstraction Layer?
It is similar to query output in Views, but I want to print it from my custom module for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`SelectQuery` implements [`SelectQuery::__toString()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::__toString/7), which is called in the contexts where a string is required.

Consider the following code.

```
global $theme_key;

$query = db_select('block')
  ->condition('theme', $theme_key)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->fields('block');

print $query;
```

Its output is the following one.

```sql
SELECT block.*
FROM 
{block} block
WHERE  (theme = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (status = :db_condition_placeholder_1)
```

To get the array of arguments used for the query, you can call [`SelectQuery::arguments()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::arguments/7).

The following code prints the query and its arguments using the functions made available from the Devel module.

```
global $theme_key;

$query = db_select('block')
  ->condition('theme', $theme_key)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->fields('block');

dpm((string) $query);
dpm($query->arguments());
```

[image: screenshot]

The Devel module is not necessary, though, and you could `drupal_set_message()` to show the output. For example, you could use the following function to get a  string with the placeholders replaced by their actual values.

```
function _get_query_string(SelectQueryInterface $query) {
  $string = (string) $query;
  $arguments = $query->arguments();

  if (!empty($arguments) && is_array($arguments)) {
    foreach ($arguments as $placeholder => &$value) {
      if (is_string($value)) {
        $value = "'$value'";
      }
    }

    $string = strtr($string, $arguments);
  }

  return $string;
}
```

The previous example code I shown would become the following one.

```
global $theme_key;

$query = db_select('block')
  ->condition('theme', $theme_key)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->fields('block');

drupal_set_message(format_string('Query: %query', array('%query' => _get_query_string($query))));

function _get_query_string(SelectQueryInterface $query) {
  $string = (string) $query;
  $arguments = $query->arguments();

  if (!empty($arguments) && is_array($arguments)) {
    foreach ($arguments as $placeholder => &$value) {
      if (is_string($value)) {
        $value = "'$value'";
      }
    }

    $string = strtr($string, $arguments);
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Notice that `SelectQuery::arguments()` returns the array of query arguments only when it is called after `SelectQuery::__toString()`, [`SelectQuery::compile()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::compile/7), or [`SelectQuery::execute()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::execute/7); otherwise, `SelectQuery::arguments()` returns `NULL`.

You could use a function similar to the following one to get the string query, with the placeholders replaced with the arguments.

Comment: I think that a function like `_get_query_string()` should have been part of the `SelectQuery` interface.

Answer (score 47):

You can use [dpq()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) to display the query, and [dpr()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpr/7) to display the result.

```
  $query = db_select('users','u');
  $query->fields('u');
  $query->condition('u.uid', 1042);
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  dpq($query); // Display the query. 
  dpr($result); // Display the query result.
```

Comment: Note that this requires the Devel module to be installed. If you do use Devel (I love it), this is the easiest way to go.

Comment: dpq() where have you been all my life!

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in a `try` `catch` block when the query fails. So not  helpful in my case if I can't debug the broken query.

Answer (score 23):

Another option is:

```
global $theme_key;

$query = db_select('block')
  ->condition('theme', $theme_key)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->fields('block');

print strtr((string) $query, $query->arguments());
```

Comment: Short and concise indeed.

Comment: No bloat / 3rd party modules required. Plus this works on queries that have not been executed, so you can print a query that fails and gives an error, `dpq` doesn't seem to allow this even in a try/catch.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: This should be the #1 answer

Comment: It's simple but not totally accurate: it misses the quote on strings and the NULL handling.

Answer (score 9):

The above answers are good when you have Devel installed and configured.

Best way to print the query without Devel is as below.

```
$query = db_select('block')
->condition('theme', $theme_key)
->condition('status', 1)
->fields('block');
//One way
echo $query->__toString();
// Second way
echo (string)$query;
```

We can use one of the above ways to print the query.

Answer (score 4):

I have a good solution that you can copy/paste your query string directly in "SQL" section in Phpmyadmin and debug your query ( I often use this method when I struggle with query)

```
$querystring=$query->__toString();
$querystring=str_replace("{",'',$querystring);
$querystring=str_replace("}",'',$querystring);
foreach($query->getArguments() as $key=> $item){

    if(!$item) {
        $item = 'NULL';
    }
    $querystring=str_replace($key.')',$item.')',$querystring);
}
dpm($querystring);
```

I hope this be usful for other guys.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 Version:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->addTag('debug')
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can print SQL String without Devel by **print_r($query->__toString);**

```
  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query
      ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
      ->condition('n.type', 'article', '=');
  $result = $query->execute();
  
  print_r($query->__toString());
```