# how to debug database query in drupal 7

Tags: debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print the query which is built using db_select()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51333/print-the-query-which-is-built-using-db-select)

How can I remove

```
:db_insert_placeholder_0
```

and table prefix from database query

```
__toString()
```

debug function.

Comment: Put the actual data into the placeholder. When I printed the queries, it gave me the table name in brackets: {table}. What is the prefix for you? Plz, provide the query, you are debugging.

Comment: it's ok, but what I should do to replace the tables prefix with {} dynamically. so can I print it directly to Navicat or PHPMyadmin for example directly.

Comment: did you try dpq function from devel module: http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7? Seems pretty good.

Comment: yes I did, but unfortunately, it doesn't remove it. In drupal 6 there is a function called db_prefix_tables() but I can't find it in drupal 7!