# Add tag to db_insert?

Tags: database

I want to do some debugging with a `db_insert` query. I tried to use the `addTag()` method, but I got an error:

```
$query = db_insert('nodes') ->addTag('my query');

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method InsertQuery_mysql::addTag()
```

Is there a way I can tag this query or otherwise make it available to `hook_query_alter`?

**Edit** This query is not giving me the expected results, and I want to know why. To see why, I need to see the query with its values. Looking in the [documentation for InsertQuery_mysql](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!mysql!query.inc/class/InsertQuery_mysql/7), it appears there's no `getArguments()` method.

Is there any way to see the values that are being inserted?

Comment: According to the API page for the "InsertQuery_mysql" class (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21mysql%21query.inc/class/InsertQuery_mysql/7) addTag() isn't a method in that class.

Comment: I want to see the actual SQL statement being sent to the server, in a way similar as to what's shown here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51338/1441 . Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why cant you use solution from link? Just cast $query to string as said in link and print or log.

Comment: The [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module should help you troubleshoot your queries.

Comment: If you cast `$query` to a string, you get the query with placeholders. I need to see the query with the values, to understand why it's not working. Replacing the placeholders with values is what is done in the `_get_query_string()` function shown in the link, but the `InsertQuery_mysql` class doesn't have a `getArguments` method.

Comment: It would be much easier to just enable mysql query logging...if not, look into [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) - you can easily get the arguments out of that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the [children classes of `Query`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/hierarchy/Query/7):

- `class DeleteQuery implements QueryConditionInterface`
- `class InsertQuery`
- `class MergeQuery implements QueryConditionInterface`
- `class SelectQuery implements SelectQueryInterface`
- `class TruncateQuery`
- `class UpdateQuery implements QueryConditionInterface`

Only [`SelectQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) implements [`addTag`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddTag/7) method. However, if you realyl are creating query object just there, you wouldn't need a tag anyway. Tags are only useful for `hook_query_alter`, and you shouldn't need to alter query you just created.

---

Your best options, as far as I know them, are:

1. Enable query log in your database
2. [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module with it's query display