# How to use database BETWEEN query?

Tags: database

I need to fetch the database records for particular date using database query , i tried some queries to fetch but it showing all records in table .

**controller.php**

```
public static function load($entry = array()){
$maxDate = \Drupal::request()->query->get('set_start_date');
$minDate = \Drupal::request()->query->get('set_end_date');
 $select = db_select('pastpayments', 'x');
 $select->fields('x');
 foreach ($entry as $field => $value) {
 $select->condition('paiddate', $maxDate, "<=");
 $select->condition('paiddate', $minDate, ">=");
}
 return $select->execute()->fetchAll();
}  

public function entryList() {
$content = array();

$content['message'] = array(
  '#markup' => $this->t('Generate a list of all entries in the database. There is no filter in the query.'),
);

$rows = array();
$headers = array(t('Member Id'), t('Name'), t('Paid Date'), t('Paid Date'));

foreach ($entries = $this->load() as $entry) {
  // Sanitize each entry.
  $rows[] = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', (array) $entry);
}
$content['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('No entries available.'),
);
// Don't cache this page.
$content['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

return $content;
```

}
[image: all records]

> how  i can fetch the table records for particular date ranges

**database query**

```
mysql> select * from pastpayments where paiddate >='2017/03/01' and paiddate <='2017/03/30';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer

```
public static function load($entry = array()) {
  $maxDate = \Drupal::request()->query->get('set_start_date');
  $minDate = \Drupal::request()->query->get('set_end_date');

 $select = db_select('pastpayments', 'x');
 $select->fields('x');
 $select->condition('paiddate', array($maxDate, $minDate), 'BETWEEN');
     $ans=$select->execute()->fetchAll();
     return $ans;
```

}

Answer (score 8):

You can use BETWEEN like this:

```
$query->condition('myfield', array(5, 10), 'BETWEEN');
```

In your case:

```
$query->condition('paiddate', array('2017/03/01', '2017/03/30'), 'BETWEEN');
```

For more information see the [Conditional Clauses](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditional-clauses) documentation.

It depends on how your dates are stored as to what min and max values you should pass in.

For example it could be a unix timestamp or it could be an actual date.
I would recommend doing a more generic select on the data to find out the format of the dates and then replicate that format in the values that you are passing in.

Comment: i modified my code like this                                                                          `$select = db_select('pastpayments', 'x');
     $select->fields('x');
     foreach ($entry as $field => $value) {
     $select->condition('paiddate', array('2017/03/01', '2017/03/30'), 'BETWEEN');
     
}
     return $select->execute()->fetchAll();
}  `                                                                                                               stil its showing all records :(

Comment: The use of between will be the same as your previous version with the <= & >=. The problem must lie somewhere else in your code. Possibly your foreach loop is adding enough different conditions that it is covering all your records? I would try printing the SQL that's in your $select object so you can make sure it is what you expect. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52761/10729 for more information on printing the SQL string.